# AWS Cron job for Lambda

Tags: cron, aws-event-bridge

I have written a Lambda to fetch some prices on Nifty Index(share market) which runs every 5 mins and uploads data to S3.

For this i have written a cron using AWS EventBridge schedule given below

15/5 9-15 ? * MON-FRI *

now the problem is this runs from 9-15 AM to 4 PM but i want to run only till 3 - 30 PM daily.
So its running 30 mins extra which is consuming more space on s3 also

Any suggestions? Couldnt find elsewhere

**Tried**
15/5 9-15 ? * MON-FRI *

Current 9-15 AM to 4 PM

**Expectation**
9-15AM to 3-30 PM

Answer (score 0):

This `15/5 9-15 ? * MON-FRI *` expression will run
**At every 5th minute from 15 through 59 past every hour from 9 through 15 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday.**

In your case between each hours 00 and 15 minutes (*1X.00-1X.15*) this cron will not execute.
So that you need more than one expression to meet your requirements.

- `30/5 9 ? * MON-FRI *` -> From 9.30-9.55
- `*/5 10-14 ? * MON-FRI *` -> From 10.00-14.55
- `0-30/5 15 ? * MON-FRI *` -> From 15.00-15.30